# Align text inside a table docx Python

Tags: docx, python-docx

How to align the text to right with python.
[image]

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('example.docx')
????
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, if your docx doesn't created or exist yet then use Document() intead of Document("example.docx")

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

doc = Document("example.docx")
para = doc.add_paragraph('This is text.')
para.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
doc.save("example.docx")
```

[image]

If you want to do this in table so try this

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

doc = Document("example.docx")
table = doc.add_table(rows=0, columns=2)
row=table.add_row().cells
p=row[0].add_paragraph('left justified text')
p.alignment=WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
doc.save("example.docx")
```